# Netty : Why use ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter in TimeServerHandler?

Tags: java, netty

I am going through netty's documentation [here](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-9) and the diagram [here](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html).
My question is, the Timeserver is writing time into the socket, for the client to read the time. Shouldn't it use the ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter ? Why is the logic in ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter ?

Couldn't understand, please explain.

Timeserver,

```
public class TimeServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) { // (1)
    final ByteBuf time = ctx.alloc().buffer(4); // (2)
    time.writeInt((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L + 2208988800L));

    final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(time); // (3)
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            assert f == future;
            ctx.close();
        }
    }); // (4)
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
```

}

TimeClient,

```
public class TimeClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = args[0];
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(); // (1)
        b.group(workerGroup); // (2)
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class); // (3)
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (4)
        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new TimeClientHandler());
            }
        });

        // Start the client.
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync(); // (5)

        // Wait until the connection is closed.
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reason we use a ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter is because, we are writing into the channel which was established by the client to the server. Since its inbound with respect to the server, we use a ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter. The Client connects to the Server, through the channel into which the server sends out the time.

Answer (score 0):

Because your server will respond to incoming messages, it will need to implement *interface* ***ChannelInboundHandler***, which defines methods for acting on inbound events.

Further, ***ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter*** has a straightforward API, and each of its methods can be overridden to hook into the event lifecycle at the appropriate point.

I just started learning Netty, hope this helps. :)